# Append to Azure blob zip file

Tags: c#, azure, zip, azure-blob-storage

I've found tons of information about how to create and upload a zip file to Azure storage, but I'm trying to see if there's a good way to add content to an existing zip file in blob storage that doesn't involve downloading the whole blob, rebuilding in memory, then uploading again.

My use case involves zipping several hundred, up to several million, items into an archive to be stored in Azure blob storage for later download.  I have code that will handle splitting so I don't wind up with a single several-GB size file, but I still run into memory management issues when dealing with large quantities of files.  I'm trying to address this by creating the zip file in blob storage, and adding subsequent files to it one by one.  I recognize this will incur cost for the additional writes, and that's fine.

I know how to use Append Blobs and Block Blobs, and I have working code to create the zip file and upload, but I can't seem to find out if there's a way to do this.  Anyone managed to accomplish this, or able to confirm that this is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with zip files, only way to add new files to an existing zip file is to download the blob, add new file to that zip file and then reupload that blob.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Guess I'll have to be a little more creative with my code.  Thanks, @Guarav_Mantri.

Answer (score 0):

Having found ourselves in a similar situation, we found the following does work for us and doesn't have a large memory overhead.

This doesn't allow a update, but using a reference of the files already stored in azure, we can iterate through them, pull them and add to here as required from a List of filesnames - that then buffers and processes the entries without downloading them all at once. You could slow down the total queue to prevent files downloading faster than they could be processed.

One thing to work out, which is why i used a ConcurrentQueue, is that the downloader which creates the available bytes to be entered into the zip - can't be from a different thread / task that is managing the ZipEntries - so this is how i got it to work, by making a SemaphoreSlim with a downloading method, that queues results, and then the Task that is building the ZipEntries - dequeues from them, and starts to add them into the ZipArchive as they become available.

This is what i used for creating that queue.

```
ConcurrentQueue<KeyValuePair<string, byte[]>> queuedFiles = new ConcurrentQueue<KeyValuePair<string, byte[]>>();
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var storedFile in storedFileNames)
{
    var t = new Task(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            getFileSemaphoreSlim.Wait();

            var storedFilePath = Path.Combine(rootDir.ToUpper(), storedFile);
            var blob = container.GetBlobClient(storedFilePath);

            if (blob.Exists())
            {
                
                using (var blobStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    blob.DownloadTo(blobStream);

                    var entryFilename = storedFile;
                    entryFilename = entryFilename.Replace("rootDir\\", "");

                    queuedFiles.Enqueue(new KeyValuePair<string, byte[]>(entryFilename, blobStream.ToArray()));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            getFileSemaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
    });

    tasks.Add(t);
    t.Start();
}
```

And then the next part of the async task, processes that queue in and creates the ZipArchive

```
var blobClient = container.GetBlockBlobClient(archiveName);
using (var stream = new AvoidFlushStream(await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(true, new BlockBlobOpenWriteOptions(), CancellationToken.None)))
using (var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true))
{
    if (csvData != null)
    {
        var csvDataEntry = zip.CreateEntry("csv.txt");
        using (var entryStream = csvDataEntry.Open())
        {
            await entryStream.WriteAsync(csvData, 0, csvData.Length);
            await entryStream.FlushAsync();
            totalBytesWritten += csvData.Length;
        }
    }

    while (!tasks.All(x => x.IsCompleted))
    {
        try
        {
            if (queuedFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                while (queuedFiles.Count > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        queuedFiles.TryDequeue(out KeyValuePair<string, byte[]> result);
                        var entry = zip.CreateEntry(result.Key);
                        using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                            await entryStream.WriteAsync(result.Value, 0, result.Value.Length);
                            await entryStream.FlushAsync();
                            totalBytesWritten += result.Value.Length;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            await Task.Delay(500); //This allows it to wait for more queued entries
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    await stream.FlushAsync();
}
```

The 'AvoidFlushStream' class, was used from a method i found on another persons site, and i can't find the reference just now - so i dont claim to take anything from him - but he outlined, that when working on a ZipEntries in AzureBlobStreams, each entry actually flushes itself after writing, which causes the max of 50,000 block entries to be maxed out quite fast .. so the customer class prevents works around this.

```
class AvoidFlushStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream source;
    private bool disposed;
    public AvoidFlushStream(Stream source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public override bool CanRead => source.CanRead;

    public override bool CanSeek => source.CanSeek;

    public override bool CanWrite => source.CanWrite;

    public override long Length => source.Length;

    public override long Position { get => source.Position; set => source.Position = value; }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Not gonna flush");
    }

    public override Task FlushAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return source.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return source.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        source.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        source.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                source.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                base.Dispose(false);
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```